# The best design for a derived class that extends functions from a base class

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have a code in which derived classes implement functions that are extensions of the same in base classes. In the example below, I want the function `do_work` to do a sequence of tasks. In the derived class `Derived`, the `do_work` function contains all the work of the base class `Base` `do_work` function, including one extra task.

What is the most elegant way of doing this from a software design perspective? Use `OPTION 1` or use `OPTION 2`?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void do_work()
        {
            do_base_task1();
            do_base_task2();
        }
    protected:
        void do_base_task1() { std::cout << "Doing base task1" << std::endl; }
        void do_base_task2() { std::cout << "Doing base task2" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        void do_work()
        {
            // OPTION 1
            do_base_task1();
            do_base_task2();
            // END OF OPTION 1

            // OPTION 2
            Base::do_work();
            // END OF OPTION 2

            do_extra_task();
        }
    protected:
        void do_extra_task() { std::cout << "Doing derived task" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Base base;
    base.do_work();

    Derived derived;
    derived.do_work();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest Option 2. Option 1 violates the DRY principle. Take a look at the [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: I'd prefer option 2 as it means you can make `do_base_task1()` and `do_base_task2()` private member functions rather than protected - they should only be accessible from within `Base` as the derived classes have no business calling them.

Comment: Additionally, option 2 lets you make the protected methods private, which helps with encapsulation.

Comment: @smkanadl How does this violate it? Please explain it.

Comment: As @101010 pointed out in his answer Option 1 forces you to re-implement `Base::do_work()`. This is some sort of violation of Don't repeat yourself! And thus a great source of subtle errors.

Comment: @smkanadl. Ah DRY means Don't Repeat Yourself. That explains a lot.

Comment: As long as all the tasks in the derived class come after the base tasks I'd definitely go with option 2 as well. I had a similar problem lately where I basically had to something like `do_base_task1()`, `do_extra_task()` and then `do_base_task2()`. There I opted for option 1 as I didn't see another straightforward way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my hummble opinion the most efficient version is:

```
void do_work() {
  Base::do_work();
  do_extra_task();
}
```

Because this way if you change `Base::do_work` implementation you won't have to pass the changes in the derived class member function `Derived::do_work` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 101010's answer, doing

```
void do_work() {
    Base::do_work();
    do_extra_task();
}
```

allows you to make `do_base_task1()` and `do_base_task2()` private member functions rather than protected which improves structure and encapsulation. The `Derived` class has no business calling these two methods so making them private instead and providing a public interface method for calling these methods (i.e. `Base::do_work()`) is better design.

Answer (score 1):

OPTION 3:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    void do_work()  // not virtual
    {
        do_base_task1();
        do_base_task2();
        do_extra_task();
    }

    //... base tasks as before

    protected:
    virtual void do_extra_task(){}
};

class Derived : public base
{
    //no do_work in here now
    protected:
    void do_extra_task() { std::cout << "Doing derived task" << std::endl; }
}
```

called in main in the same way as in your example

This way you know that all derived classes will call the base do work (you can't forget it in one of the derived classes) and if a particular derived class has no extra work to do, then it doesn't need to define do_work or do_extra_tasks. Less repetition because you don't repeatedly define do_work.

This is the non virtual interface pattern.

Comment: This would not allow people to add extra functiodnality without editing the base class.

Comment: Why not? you add the extra functionality by overriding the virtual do_extra_task function in your derived classes. It does prevent the derived classes from writing a do_work that avoids the base class actions, so if they are optional this wouldn't be the pattern to use, but where all derived classes must call the base class work then this code is self-documenting in that respect. This is an established pattern. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
#include<iostream>

struct B {
    virtual void doWork() = 0;
};

template<class D>
struct T: B {
    void doWork() override {
        taskT();
        static_cast<D*>(this)->taskD();
    }

private:
    void taskT() { std::cout << "taskT" << std::endl; }
};

struct S: T<S> {
    void taskD() { std::cout << "taskD" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    B *b = new S;
    b->doWork();
}
```

This is based on CRTP idiom.
If you are designing a small library, this option takes completely in charge of calling the right method when it's time to call it.
The user of your library even doesn't know that the methods in the base class exist, but one knows that the method of the derived class will be called by contract.
Even more, `taskD` is not part of the interface of the base class, so you cannot execute the extra task from a reference to `B` (unless you call `doWork`, and it actually executes all the tasks in the right order).